# Can we use MoneyField() field as output_field in Django Case

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset

I am trying to set a default value In Django Case but it complains `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'Money'`

Here is my code

```
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField
def method(self):

    clauses = [
        When(
         value_currency=u.value_currency,
         then=Value(u.value)
        )
        for u in Price.objects.all()
    ]
    return Case(
        *clauses,
        default=Value(Money('0.0', settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY)),
        output_field=MoneyField()
    )

In [1]: type(Price.objects.first().value)
Out[1]: djmoney.money.Money
```

I have used that method in query set like this

```
   qs = qs.annotate(
        _price=self.method()
    )
```

I can use `DecimalField()` Like this and it works.

```
def method(self):
    clauses = [
        When(
         value_currency=u.value_currency,
         then=Value(u.value.amount)
        )
        for u in Price.objects.all()
    ]
    return Case(
        *clauses,
        default=Value(0.0),
        output_field=models.DecimalField()
    )
```

But I want `qs._price` to be `Money` type. Can we use `Money` field value in Django Case?

Comment: Exactly *what* do you try to do? It looks like you aim to exchange to a certain currency? Perhaps that is better done at the Django/Python level?

Comment: There are two different models for Price and I want to return both price within single queryset. And both prices can be mapped to each other using few conditions